# Function like "connectify" on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, android

I know there was a lot of questions about this, but my problem is kind of different.

I have a tablet with Android. On Windows I used to host wifi from my PC. I used an application called `connectify`. On Ubuntu. I can use the "Use as hotspot" option but it hosts "Ad-hoc" network. Android doesn't see ad-hoc networks. 
How can I make a wifi network similar to what `connectify` did?

My PC is connected to Internet using a cable and I have external adapter.

Sorry for my english, and thanks for the help :)

Comment: ubuntu doesn't support natively, meanwhile you can try this, [How To Set Up A Wireless Hotspot (Access Point Mode) That Supports Android In Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try ap-hotspot. It works with Android devices, but it has only two problems: no GUI and you can't share the network that you use to connect to the router (example: wifi connected - cannot share wifi).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
sudo ap-hotspot configure
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

The hotspot is now active and ready to go. The hotspot can be stopped by using the command:

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

Comment: "Your wireless card or driver does not support Access Point mode" - this is what i get when i try this.
PS: connectify works in my system

Comment: You are getting this error because your driver doesn't support Access Point mode.

Comment: The package **ap-hotspot** is not available now.

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you have a wireless card you can click on the internet connections on the toolbar at the top of the screen and near the bottom there's an option to "create new wifi network"

Comment: this option creates ad-hoc too. Android dosn't see this. :(